# Word for giving a conflicting response

Tags: terminology

What is the term given to a conflicted reply within the same response?

For example, “Maybe I stole the money, but then again, maybe I didn’t.”

Comment: Being evasive, equivocating, noncommittal

Comment: That's not a conflicting response; it's as Jim said and either way, what did your own dictionaries, thesauruses or search engines leave unclear?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for "equivocate".
[Thesaurus.com definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/equivocate?s=t) is
"to use ambiguous or unclear expressions, usually to avoid commitment or in order to mislead; prevaricate or hedge"

This term suggests the speaker is trying to avoid any outright lie — compare to "prevaricate", which involves a more deliberate effort to mislead.

Answer (score 0):

**to sidestep**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sidestep)

Verb     1. sidestep - avoid or try to avoid fulfilling, **answering**, or performing (duties, **questions**, or issues);

As in:

“Maybe I stole the money, but then again, maybe I didn’t” sidestepping her answer.

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest **contradiction**. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contradiction):

> a proposition, statement, or phrase that asserts or implies both the
>   truth and falsity of something

and

> a statement or phrase whose parts contradict each other

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. But there’s an actual term for this sort of response. I saw it somewhere a few weeks ago and for the life of me I can’t seem to recall it.

Comment: How are “Maybe I did” and “Maybe I didn’t” contradictory?  They each allow for the other.